# What is a soil spreader called in the U.S? Are they available here?

Tags: lawn, soil, lawn-repair

I just watched a YouTube video on how to top dress your lawn.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M77S86Sib1I

The guy who does the video is in Australia. He has a handy tool that he calls a soil leveler. I found a link to one:

http://www.bunnings.com.au/cyclone-top-soil-spreader_p3361061

But I can't find one for sale here. Do we have these in the U.S.? And if so, what are they called and where can I get one?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it would be easy to make with some electrical conduit and a few bolts/nuts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trulutes or soil levellers are similar - they're primarily intended for top dressing lawns, but are similar to the one in your link and can be used for spreading out materials. I can't seem to find any available in the States though, so they're either not available, or called something else.

Ah, just found something - they're called Gravel leveler/Easy spreaders in the States. Not sure where you are, but Rittenhouse, a supplier in CA is, where I found that out.

Comment: Farmers call them manure spreaders as seen here http://www.deere.com/wps/dcom/en_US/products/equipment/frontier_implements/livestock_and_equine_equipment/manure_spreaders/manure_spreaders.page A little big for home use...

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty neat tool but I haven't seen them available in the US. You can do with out it and do a good job topdressing with just a bow rake and a spring tine rake that they also use in the video.

Some other tools that are available possibly for rent are called top dressers or compost spreaders. Think of a very heavy duty drop spreader. Some are even powered.

I've also seen a rolling compost soil spreader. It's basically a large drum made out of expanded metal and has a handle like a giant push reel mower. You fill it up with compost and roll it around your lawn. Fill it up with compost and the compost drops out of the holes in the expanded lath as you roll. I've seen some sold commercially and ones that people made themselves.